# Redirect to chrome extension using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im trying to launch a Chrome extenstion using the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <script>
        (function(){
        var chromeId = 'theIdOfMyChromeExtension';
        window.location.href = "chrome-extension://"+chromeId+"/main.html";
        })();
    </script> 
</html>
```

If I open this file in Chrome manually it launches the extension fine, however if this HTML is the response of an HTTP GET on a webserver, Chrome redirects to about:blank.

BTW, if I do this in Firefox it will obviously fail but It will at least do the redirection to the extension URL.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: try now, put path to main.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

you should add this to your manifest as well...

```
 "web_accessible_resources": ["main.html"],
```

add this to your extension manifest

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.speficifDomain.com/*"]
}
```

Comment: Muhammad, thanks for your comment, however its still not working.  Do I need to set the host or do something else first?